# sqlite library cannot update database file that has been installed

Tags: c++, sqlite

I can open, read and update, using the sqlite3 command line tool, a database in a file that has been placed by an installer , like this:

```
C:\ProgramData\spectronix\oximeter>C:\Users\James\code\bin\sqlite3 spectrumalpha.dat
SQLite version 3.16.2 2017-01-06 16:32:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE run ( run INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timestamp, desc );
CREATE TABLE distance ( hwid, distance );
CREATE TABLE spectrum ( run, timestamp, hwid, distance, data );
CREATE TABLE waveDescription ( run, timestamp, hwid );
CREATE TABLE wave ( wave, idx, data );
sqlite> select desc from run where run is 5;
update from sqlite3 tool
sqlite> UPDATE run SET desc='update #2 from sqlite3 tool' WHERE run IS 5;
sqlite> select desc from run where run is 5;
update #2 from sqlite3 tool
```

But when I run this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main()
{
    sqlite3 * db;
    sqlite3_stmt *st = 0;
    int ret;
    char const * tail = 0;

    ret = sqlite3_open("C:/ProgramData/spectronix/oximeter/spectrumalpha.dat",&db);

    std::cout << "working with db in "
        << sqlite3_db_filename( db, "main" ) << "\n";

    // read initial value
    ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(
              db,
              "SELECT desc FROM run WHERE run IS 5;"
              , -1, &st, &tail );
    if( ret != SQLITE_OK )
        throw std::runtime_error("sqlite first read");
    sqlite3_step( st );
    std:: cout << "first read is " << sqlite3_column_text(st, 0) << "\n";
    sqlite3_finalize( st );

    return 0;
}
```

the output shows a previous version of the data

```
working with db in C:\ProgramData\spectronix\oximeter\spectrumalpha.dat
first read is test4
```

the other strange thing is that the library code refuses to update the data

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

    int main()
    {
        sqlite3 * db;
        sqlite3_stmt *st = 0;
        int ret;
        char const * tail = 0;

        ret = sqlite3_open("C:/ProgramData/spectronix/oximeter/spectrumalpha.dat",&db);

        std::cout << "working with db in "
            << sqlite3_db_filename( db, "main" ) << "\n";

        // read initial value
        ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(
                  db,
                  "SELECT desc FROM run WHERE run IS 5;"
                  , -1, &st, &tail );
        if( ret != SQLITE_OK )
            throw std::runtime_error("sqlite first read");
        sqlite3_step( st );
        std:: cout << "first read is " << sqlite3_column_text(st, 0) << "\n";
        sqlite3_finalize( st );

        // update value
        ret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(
                  db,
                  "UPDATE run SET desc = 'new_value' WHERE run IS 5;"
                  , -1, &st, &tail );
        if( ret != SQLITE_OK )
            throw std::runtime_error("sqlite update error");
        sqlite3_finalize( st );
        std::cout << sqlite3_changes( db ) << " rows updated\n";

        return 0;
    }
```

outputs

```
working with db in C:\ProgramData\spectronix\oximeter\spectrumalpha.dat
first read is test4
0 rows updated
```

I tried moving the database into the working directory of the application, changing the call to open the database to

```
ret = sqlite3_open("spectrumalpha.dat",&db);
```

but the same problems occur.

So, finally, I deleted the database and recreated it from scratch all over again.  The problem, whatever it may have been, is gone!  Anyone have any ideas what it might have been - in case it recurs?

The next the day the problem returned, after I used an **installer** to write the database file.

Comment: What is your table structure? `UPDATE run SET desc='update #2 from sqlite3 tool' WHERE run IS 5` looks like an odd query

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have posted the schema near the top of my question

Comment: And a row with `run` set to `5` definitely exists?

Comment: Yes.  Look at "first read is test4" from "SELECT desc FROM run WHERE run IS 5;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer was creating the file with write permission for some users and readonly for others.  A typical snag for unix, but not something I am used to having to deal with on windows.